# Material UI v5 DateTimePicker (controlled) onClose trigger input focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

Try use 2 DateTimePicker as siblings, but when click on second (DateTimePicker still opened) - open other DateTimePicker, but focus still on first input. Help, please.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-architecture-hbbs2r?file=/src/Mui.js

I need focused input, when i clicked first time, but when i click other input - opened new DateTimePicker and focus on this new input.

Answer (score 0):

Fix this by more controlling of open prop. Instead DateTimePicker "open" use PopperProps "open" with ClickAwayListener for closing.
https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-mcclintock-8to7h5?file=/src/Mui.js